# SQL Server DataBase Synchronization

Tags: sql-server-2005, synchronization, multiprocessing

Is the SQL Server synchronized to be compatible with many processes? Do i have to make synchronization to be possible to work with DataBases so that more than 1 process be used at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server is designed to handle multiple processes working on the same data simultaneously (via various lock mechanisms etc). You can also control the level of synchronization / isolation via `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION` statement. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will manage the synchronization for you. See [database transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) and [isolation levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what you need. If all your processes are reading from the database - than you can ignore the concurrency altogether.
If you have complex write operations, which need to execute multiple queries, and you wish them to be atomic - look into **transactions** (or if your application allows it try to execute them from a single process).